# QT Display a QWidget above QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qgraphicsscene

Currently I have a [`QGraphicsScene`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html) that is put inside a [`QGraphicsView`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html) and is shown on the display. I add all my elements to my `scene` that I set as the active scene.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsView w;
    GameScene *gameScene = new GameScene(); // GameScene extends QGraphicsScene, adds tons of elements to the scene
    w.setScene(gameScene);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Above this scene I want a bar that contains several layout elements, like several [`QProgressBar`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprogressbar.html).

For what I have found so far, QWidget's can be positioned easily. I've made already a widget of what I need to be displayed above the scene:

```
QWidget *dummyWidget = new QWidget();
QFormLayout *formLayout = new QFormLayout;
QProgressBar *bar1 = new QProgressBar();
QProgressBar *bar2 = new QProgressBar();
bar1->setValue(20);
bar2->setValue(100);
formLayout->addRow("&Health:", bar1);
formLayout->addRow("&Energy:", bar2);
dummyWidget->setLayout(formLayout);
dummyWidget->show();
```

[image: Health- and energy bars]

But how do I get this to be displayed above my `QGraphicsScene`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display your widget above the view you can have a layout similar to the one for `dummyWidget` and add the widget and view in it :

```
    QGraphicsView w;

    QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
    QFormLayout *formLayout2 = new QFormLayout(widget);

    QWidget *dummyWidget = new QWidget();
    QFormLayout *formLayout = new QFormLayout;
    QProgressBar *bar1 = new QProgressBar();
    QProgressBar *bar2 = new QProgressBar();
    bar1->setValue(20);
    bar2->setValue(100);
    formLayout->addRow("&Health:", bar1);
    formLayout->addRow("&Energy:", bar2);
    dummyWidget->setLayout(formLayout);

    formLayout2->addRow("", dynamic_cast<QWidget*>(dummyWidget));
    formLayout2->addRow("", dynamic_cast<QWidget*>(&w));

    widget->show();
```

If you want to add the widget in the scene, you can use `QGraphicsScene::addWidget`  which creates a new `QGraphicsProxyWidget` for widget, adds it to the scene, and returns a pointer to the proxy :

```
QGraphicsProxyWidget * item = gameScene->addWidget(dummyWidget);
item->setPos(100,100);
item->setZValue(1);
```

You can also add it to an item :

```
item->setParentItem(anOtherItem);
```

Comment: Works fine, but is there also a way to really display it above the whole scene, or rather, display the scene under the widget and have the widget extend to the width of the screen? The scene I have positions items across the whole scene, and using this method I would have to offset them all by the height of the widget.

Comment: Do you want to display your widget inside the scene or you just want it to be above the view and out side of it?

Comment: It does not have to display inside the scene, I want it to display above my scene.

Comment: @arbitter There are many ways to do it. You can use a layout and add both the widget and view in it. I have updated the answer to show one possible way.